# Set DVI version output in xelatex?

Tags: xetex, texlive, dvi

After upgrade to TeXLive 2015 I can no longer convert xdv output of `xelatex` to svg with `dvisvgm`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}

$x^2$

\end{document}
```

Compilation:

```
$ xelatex -no-pdf mwe.tex 
$ dvisvgm mwe.xdv 
DVI error: DVI format 6 not supported
```

Is there a way to make xelatex output the previous DVI version 5? (which is [supported by dvisvgm](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm))

Note: `dvisvgm` support for DVI version 6 [has already been requested](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues/47).

Comment: I think there is no way. Lets wait for the update of dvisvgm.

Comment: I've just added support for the new XDV format to dvisvgm. The code is available through the GitHub repository and will be part of the next release.

Comment: @Martin: great! It works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in comments, the DVI (XDV) version produced by XeTeX is fixed and not user-controllable. Also as noted, `dvisvgm` has been updated to work with the latest XeTeX version so this is no longer an issue.